# Body shape of a bioengineered tool-using fish

Tags: genetic-engineering, tools

So, the dolphins are revolting! They want rights! They demand equality! They insist upon humans sharing all those wonderfully human things with them, like jobs and housing and social media and translators so they can tell zoologist to STOP #&*%ING PATRONISING THEM YES WE CAN JUGGLE BEACH BALLS THANK YOU!

Problem is, dolphins don’t have hands. No piano playing or basketball for these guys. Another problem is that it turns out dolphins are purist and conservative to a fault, and the Dolphin Potentate vehemently opposed cyborg arms, “which would ruin our figure!” Ergo, humans decide that rather than modify the dolphins to use tools, they should put the bioengineering kit they got for Christmas to good use, and *create a life form that can use tools for them.*

Since dolphins are aquatic, they model this life form on a fish, but I am not sure what shape it should be, given the staggering variation in bony fish body shapes. What shape should a bioengineered tool-using fish be?

Comment: An Octopus is not a fish, but already pretty smart and would already be able to use tools if it wanted. (I've seen one unscrew a jam)

Comment: VTC: Story-based question. There is no right answer to this because only the requirements of your story can answer the question. Do you want claws? tentacles? hands? When you say "tools" do you mean hammers? computers? cameras? Have you even thought through how the tools your story wants can be used underwater? And once we know what kinds of appendages are needed, what do we know of its shape? Round? oblong? carapaced? squishy? None of this is answerable by us ... only by you, *the author.*

Comment: This is a major theme in the Uplift series by David Brin. Good books. I recommend them. However, it's too complex for a simple question and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catfish-shaped.

Giant catfish are already sort of similar in overall body shape to ancient anomalocaridids, which did in fact have arms. And Catfish already have barbell appendages coming out of their faces in about the same positions that anomalocaridids had their arms.

So, just engineer a giant catfish with barbells replaced with jointed bony arms attached to their heads.

Answer (score 0):

**Beach ball shaped.**

Because this life form is explicitly created to help the dolphins.
And it is established in OP that

> YES WE CAN JUGGLE BEACH BALLS THANK YOU!

Dolphins should therefore be able to juggle their toolfish into position so that these fish can use tools on the dolphins behalf.

The toolfish might be sort of upset when they realize they were created to make fun of the dolphins for being adamantly no-armed conservatives.  Then I realized that humans exist because of the same sort of bad joke and God pranking the angels.  The beachball shaped toolfish are our spirit brothers.

And a beachball shaped toolfish should be your new avatar, user98816, and your new name should be Toolfish.  You can do better than "user98816" and that purple doily.